# What is the difference between using Invoke method vs Step and Final methods in a user defined SQLiteFunction (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I am new to .NET programming and have come across two different forms of user-defined SQLiteFunctions that seem common. One form I see is:

```
[SQLiteFunction(Name="ToUpper", Arguments=1, FuncType=FunctionType.Scalar)]
    public class ToUpper : SQLiteFunction {
        public override object Invoke(object[] args) {
            return args[0].ToString().ToUpper();
        }
    }

[SQLiteFunction(Name="SUM", Arguments=1, FuncType=FunctionType.Aggregate)]
    public override void Step(object[] args, int n, ref object data) {
        //Do stuff to data
    }

    public override object Final(object data) {
        return data;
    }
```

Why would one form be used over another to essentially do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Invoke is for operating on a single object, like

```
select ToUpper(name) from products
```

The Step/Final is for operating over a range of rows, Step is called for each row, and the Final is called to return the result.

```
select sum(price) from products
```